# React Bootstrap Modal - some elements of background not shaded

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I'm using the React Bootstrap modal, and when its open, the background is typically shaded and overlayed with the modal. However, certain elements (specifically the Material UI Drawer http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) don't get shaded and render over the modal. Does anyone know why this is?

I tried messing around with the zIndex values for the components, and made sure the modal's was higher, but got the same result. The Material UI Drawer has a 'zDepth' attribute which I also tried changing, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post with the code you currently have, thanks!

Comment: the default z-index of the material-ui drawer is 1300 (its in the theme at "muiTheme.zIndex.drawer"). So the z-index of your modal's overlay/background needs to be something higher than 1300. Have you considered just using material-ui's Dialog instead?

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the z-index of the modal and modal-backdrop higher to 1300 solves the issue for me!